# Assembly in Custom Workflow Action?

Tags: workflow, error, custom-actions

I am making a custom workflow action.  I have written my code in the .cs file, made the AllowedTypes.xml and the .actions4 file and deployed them to the workflow manager and added the assembly to the GAC etc. etc.  Upon loading up sharepoint designer to test the workflow action I received an error saying that the assembly used in my project (AllowedTypes.xml and myFile.actions4) does not exist.

I think in general I do not understand this assembly and how it interacts with the workflow manager and where the assembly comes from.  What am I missing here and why am I getting this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found documentation on the matter. Here is a script to run to find the publicKeyToken for your assembly from the .snk file

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2010/11/05/quick-tip-find-the-four-part-name-for-an-assembly.aspx